# How do I add a watermark to an image with OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, watermark

Is there any way to add a watermark image to another image using the OpenCV library?

I am working with OpenCV and C++.

Comment: Describe the steps you've taken.

Comment: This sounds like a question google will be happy to answer...

Comment: I have the Mat image and doing color correction on the image and a visible watermark needs to be inserted after that. Is there any way i can do it with opencv. Tried to google but couldnt find anything using opencv

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html#adding-images).

Here is some (non-tested) code:

```
 Mat watermark = imread("watermarkimage.png")
 Mat img = imread("yourimage.jpg");
 //assuming the watermark has same number of channel and size as your_image
 Mat watermarked = (0.8 * img) +  (0.2 * watermark)
```

Answer (score 0):

You  can add text watermark on the image using [cv::putText](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext) function of opencv.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: blend the original image (90%) and the copy with the watermark text/graphics added (10%).

Comment: Could you please help with an example